# iteration of loop in formula vba

Tags: vba, excel, loops, excel-formula

I'm trying to sum a variable range of data starting at row 3. sortedRow is the row # of the end of the data. lColumn is the last column used as a number.

I'm trying to sum the data in row 1, column H - lColumn.

I need to have the formula calculate the sum of column G, then iterating on referenced column by the current iteration (which will be columns h through x)

I've taken Scott Craner's advice and edited my code as

```
Dim lColumn As Long
lColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
sortedRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Integer 'iterated column sum cell 
For i = 8 To lColumn

    Cells(1, i).Value =Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range(Cells(3,7), 
    Cells(sortedRow, 7)), Range(Cells(3, i), Cells(sortedRow, i)), 1)

Next i
```

The cells are not being updated with their values though.
It feels like I'm missing something really obvious with actually applying the number to the cell. I thought the above would do it.

added lColumn declaration because of issue with the formula being applied
added sortedRow declaration.

[image: basically this. But with variable column lengths and number of columns]

basically this. But with variable column lengths and number of columns.
It didn't matter for Column H that there was "#VALUE" in the volume column. So I assume it doesn't matter for the other columns.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: i is a number and you are trying to use it as an alpha character. Try Range(cells(3,i),cells(sortedRow,i)) in the second part of your SumIfs.

Comment: Could you clarify cells(3,I),...

is that supposed to be lower case i?

Comment: Yes, sorry I fixed it.  It is hard to type an 'i' without my fingers automatically hitting the shift key.

Comment: I see. 

I'm getting a compile error now at "$G3:$G" & sortedRow...
at the ampersand. I'm guessing I need to apply the same type of solution and change to Range(cells(3,7),cells(sortedRow,7))?
Seems to have fixed it.

The formulas aren't posting their answers in the sheet now. Perhaps I'm missing something else

Comment: Yes, sorry you can put range("G3:G" & sortedRow),  VBA requires that you tell it that it is a range.  It is a little different nomenclature than the formula bar in excel.

Comment: The range issue seems to have been fixed with your solution. Thank you! I think I'm missing something obvious though, as the cells H1-lColumn1 are not updating with an answer

Comment: Try putting the formula in manually into one cell and see if you get an answer.  It may be with the formula itself and the way you are using sumifs.  Without a preview of the data it is hard for us to help on that.

Comment: No luck with that. The formula is applying to the first cell but not any other cells. This seems like an iteration problem, but I don't see why its not working.

Comment: So just so I get what you are trying to do, you want to sum only the cells in column G rows 3 through variable sorted row where column variable i rows 3 through variable sortedrow = 1?  I assume you have a grid that has a bunch of ones in various columns to denoted whether to add it to the sum.  Is this correct?  Could you post an example of the data?

Comment: In the highlighted column you are trying to add #Value.  It will not work.  Take the 1 off that row and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have problems here.

```
("$G3:$G" & sortedRow, i & "3:" & i & sortedRow, 1)

("$G3:$G" & sortedRow & "," & i & "3:" & i & sortedRow, 1)
```

But you still have issues in there. If i=4 and sortedRow=12 let's say, this is what you would have.

```
(G3:G12,43:412, 1)
```

So you need to fix your Criteria_range1. I'm not clear from your question what you want the criteria to be.

Here is info on the arguments. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193011.aspx

Comment: I've edited my question a bit with comments from Scott (above). I the problem with my code has shifted to actually putting the answer into the cell now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved after fixing #VALUE cells in the sumifs columns I was trying to add. I made a conditional statement that set all errors to equal zero. This allowed the loop to function.